# Почему получается fasle при равенстве типов?

Tags: php

Как я понимаю вся суть в внутренем представлении и чтобы получить точное значение надо ограничить до 5 знаков после точки ?

$x = 8 - 6.4; 
var_dump($x);
$y = 1.6;
var_dump($y);
var_dump($x == $y);